# Why my arrow is not visible over blue bar?

Tags: css

Div of "white tab" has position relative and it is a parent div.

Its child div is red arrow which has position absolute and z-index:1000. But it is getting hidden in the blue bar.

[image]

```css
.task-notification .arrow:after {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid #bf4b4b;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 73%;
  top: -14px;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 1000;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu notifications task-notes" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
  <div class="arrow"></div>
  <div class="notification-heading"> </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: please provide code to help better

Comment: <ul class="dropdown-menu notifications task-notes" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
<div class="arrow"></div>
                        <div class="notification-heading">
                        </div>
                    </ul>

Comment: css code
.task-notification .arrow:after{
width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
    border-right: 15px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 15px solid #bf4b4b;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 73%;
    top: -14px;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 3000;
    opacity: 1;
 }

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0ngG.png

Comment: please add your code to the intial question. and replicate your problem. from your picture....it seems like you have a `z-index` issue

Comment: edit the question to update code and image into question it self rather then in comments

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work in the code explorer.

I think you need to set `overflow: visible;` to the parent div to allow the arrow to be seen.

Please try above, and if that doesn't help.

Please update your code so it can be seen in code explorer, or give a url to test.

Hope this helps.